# pdo::query fetch_class: how to retrieve a single resulting object?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I have a DB table `Entity` and a corresponding DTO class `Entity` (no constructor arguments).

When I do this:

```
$entity=$connection->query("Select * FROM Entity WHERE id='1'",
    PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'Entity',
    NULL);
```

Then `$entity` is a `PDOStatement` containing one object of class `Entity`.

How can I retrieve this one Entity object without looping over `$entity` with a `foreach`?

`PDOStatment:fetchObject` didn't seem like a good solution, because it's going to map the `Entity` object in the `PDOStatement` on a new `Entity` object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do

```
$entity = $connection->query("Select * FROM Entity WHERE id='1'",
    PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'Entity',
    NULL)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

I've never tried using the query method like that before, so this may not work.